# When does getClassLoader() of Class throws SecurityException

Tags: java

From docs in `getClassLoader()` of Class,

> If a security manager is present, and the caller's class loader is not
>   null and the caller's class loader is not the same as or an ancestor
>   of the class loader for the class whose class loader is requested,
>   then this method calls the security manager's checkPermission method
>   with a RuntimePermission("getClassLoader") permission to ensure it's
>   ok to access the class loader for the class.

When does `getClassLoader()` throws SecurityException? I would think the caller's class  loader is always the same as the class loader for the class whose class loader is requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would think the caller's class loader is always the same as the class loader for the class whose class loader is requested.

You would be wrong about that.

Suppose that your class is untrusted code that has been loaded inside a security sandbox, using the sandbox classloader.  And that your class is calling `getClassLoader()` on (say) a system class that has been loaded by the default classloader.

In this scenario, the classloaders will be different, and there will be a security manager, so a `checkPermission` call will be made to check that the (untrusted) code is permitted to get the classloader.  If it isn't permitted, then a `SecurityException` will be thrown.

---

Note: "the caller's class loader" means the classloader that loaded the class that is *making* the call.

For example, in this code:

```
public class Foo {
    public void method(Bar bar) {
        bar.getClass().getClassLoader()
    }
}
```

the "caller" is `method`, and the "caller's class loader" for that `getClassLoader()` call is the classloader for the `Foo` class.  That will be tested to see if it is the same classloader for the `Bar` class.  (Or more precisely the class that is returned by the `getClass()` call.)

Comment: I'm not sure which two classes's ClassLoader the docs refer to. Does `caller` mean "the class wrap the call of getClassLoader()", and the other is the clsss  whose class object invocates `getClassLoader()`?